# Non-trivial integral forms of algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, examples, soft-question

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\mathbf{C}$-algebra then an integral form would be a subring $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$ such that the canonical map $\mathcal{B}  \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ is a bijection.

For some algebras there is an obvious integral form in the following sense: there is a preferred $\mathbf{C}$-basis for $\mathcal{A}$ and the $\mathbf{Z}$-span of that basis is $\mathcal{B}$.  Now my question is do we have examples where $\mathcal{B}$ is non-obvious? In other words the basis coming from $\mathcal{B}$ would look very strange for those who only work with $\mathcal{A}$. Is there such an example where $\mathcal{A}$ is commutative?

Comment: Minor quibble: I think you want $\mathcal B$ to be something like free as $\mathbb Z$-module. Otherwise $\mathcal B$ could be for instance a $\mathbb Q$-vector space (note that for a $\mathbb Q$-algebra $\mathcal B$ we have $\mathcal B\bigotimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb C=\mathcal B\bigotimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 4):

Finite dimensional algebras (over alg. closed fields) which are of finite representation type have *multiplicative bases*, that is, bases such that the product of two of its elements is either an element of the basis or zero. This is a difficult and beautiful theorem of R. Bautista, P. Gabriel, A. Roiter and L. Salmerón.

This gives rather special integral forms for such algebras and, in general, it is quite non-obvious how to get them.

Answer (score 3):

There are many important integral forms with a "strange" appearance. Namely, we have
1) Kostant's form for a finite-dimensional complex simple Lie algebra, see the classical Humphrey's book;
2) Garland's form for the loop algebra of a finite-dimensional complex simple Lie algebra $g$, see the proper Garland's paper. In this case appear some elements given by the coefficient of some series given by the exponential of a suitable generating series with coeficients in the loop Cartan subalgebra of $g$.

For commutative cases we probably have those expected elements from a $\mathbb{C}$-basis, since the "strange" elements always come from brackets in the non-commutative case!

Hope help you,

Answer (score 1):

I got some "strange" integral forms when I generalized Garland's integral forms for the loop algebras to the map algebras of complex simple Lie algebras. The map algebras are a generalization of the loop algebras where we replace $\mathbb{C}[t^{\pm1}]$ by any algebra A. My integral forms are valid when A has a basis which is closed under multiplication. Thanks Mariano for letting me know that they are valid in more cases than I previously thought.